# Unwrapping measurements from Adxl345 accelerometer

Tags: arduino, i2c, accelerometer, calibration

I am trying to read acceleration values from a ADXL345 via I2C. I've successfully configured the accelerometer with a resolution of 16G.

**Test 1**: 180° rotation along the y axis in 16G resolution. The acceleration along the Z axis is shown below:

[image]

Using a 16g configuration, the resolution is too low. I changed it to 2g in order to get a more accurate value of gravity and performed the same test.

**Test 2**: 180° rotation along the y axis in 2G resolution. The acceleration along the Z axis is shown below:

[image]

As you can see, the is a roll over effect probably caused by the number of bits used in the register to save the value. With 16g mode the module uses a 13 bit register, with 2/4/8g mode it uses a 10bit register.

Which approach do you suggest to reconstruct the acceleration value?

In [this](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/34498/recovering-data-from-a-saturated-accelerometer) question @davidcary mentioned the roll over effect.

**EDIT**

I am reading two bytes, it is the same code I used for the 16g mode

```
def read_word(self,adr):
     high = self.bus.read_byte_data(self.address, adr)
     low = self.bus.read_byte_data(self.address, adr+1)
     val = (high << 8) + low
     return val

def read_word_2c(self,adr):
     val = self.read_word(adr)
    if (val >= 0x8000):
       return -((65535 - val) + 1)
    else:
       return val
[...]

accel_zout = adx.read_word_2c(0x36)
```

Here is a screenshot of the registers containing the Zaxis values

[image]

***Note***

Here is another problem, I will open another question for this but it is worth pointing out the following problem. Please focus on the Z axis only

**Test**: tilt from 0° to 180° and back to 0° twice, then from 0° to -180° and back to 0° twice.

**Figure 1**: Raw data

[image]

As you can see, the shift is not costant. The average shift is around 58.000 but sometimes it is smaller than this. If we apply the same correction to all shify occurence we will end up with this:

**Figure 2**: Unwrapped data

[image]

If the threshold after which the correction should be applied is not correctly defined, the resulting data won't be accurate. In *Figure 2* the acceleration along the Z axis after the test is different from the initial zero value which means disaster...

Comment: How many bits are you reading? Looks like you are ignoring the top bits.

Comment: I am reading two bytes. Please see my edit

Comment: Maybe have a look at: 
https://github.com/GiovanniBalestrieri/Tenzo/tree/master/FSAE/Acquisizione%20Acc/Dati
or
https://github.com/GiovanniBalestrieri/Tenzo/blob/master/Matlab/%5B1%5D%20CPanel/SNZ95UDUD.mat

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reconstruction you are looking for is called **unwrapping**. I have implemented this in C++ with good results last year when measuring the total revolution of a car wheel. In matlab:
[link](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/unwrap.html)

```
Q = unwrap(P,tol)
```

The "roll over" observed (actually, a *wrapping*) is not caused by register overflow, but by the signal change of measured gravity acceleration. The tolerance *tol* should be half the peak-to-peak amplitude observed.

In C, it would be something like this (haven't tested this, but the idea is here):

```
void unwrap(int *P, int tol, int len)
{
    for (int index = 1; index < len; index++)
    {
        // Upwards wrapping
        while (P[index-1] - P[index] > tol)
        {
            P[index] += 2*tol;
        }
        // Downwards wrapping
        while (P[index] - P[index-1] > tol)
        {
            P[index] -= 2*tol;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you Vicente! Exhaustive answer! I correct the title

Comment: How do you handle noise in conjunction with unwrapping?

Comment: Maybe a median filter with a 3 samples window will do the job

Comment: @UserK In my application I had designed and implemented a FIR that filtered data input before unwrapping. It was pretty efficient in C++ using _deque_ containers. You could determine window length and coefficients to your needs using matlab toolboxes. The maths behind FIR implementation is as simple as a dot product, the design is the tricky bit.